# Show by means of an example that a limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

Show by means of an example that $\lim_{x\to 4} $[$f(x)$ + $g(x)$] may exist even though neither $\lim_{x\to 4} $$f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x\to 4} $$g(x)$ exists.

I'm having some problems with this question. I'm not really sure how to go about it. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $f$ so that the limit for $f$ does not exist, and then choose $g=-f$.

Comment: I'm not really understanding it. Could you please give a detailed explanation?

Comment: @Sab If $f=-g$, what is $\lim \limits_{x\to 4}\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud 4?
/Chars

Comment: @Sab No, let's try again. If $f=-g$, then $\lim \limits_{x\to 4}(f(x)+\underbrace{g(x)}_{=-f(x)})$. What do you get inside the limit?

Comment: @GitGud It's 0?

Comment: @Sab Yes. And what is $\lim \limits_{x\to 4}(0)$?

Comment: @GitGud Ahh, it's 0. I see what mistake I made. But how do I present this solution in an elegant way, with all the theorems listed etc(if there are any involved)?

Comment: @Sab This doesn't solve the problem. This just explains the hint. You know have to find a suitable $f$, i.e., one whose limit doesn't exist at $4$.